# Code-first database mapping, table missing (wasn't created) for many-to-many relationship

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, many-to-many, dbcontext

I am building ASP.NET webforms application using Entity Framework 6.1, with code-first approach to generate database. I have two tables, **Product** and **Tags**, in many-to-many relationship. Classes are below:

```
public class Product
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products{ get; set; }
}
```

I want two junction tables out of this relationship **ProductTags** and **ProductTagsTradeFor**. So I overrided *OnModelCreating* of *WebsiteDbContext*.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany<Tag>(s => s.Tags).WithMany(c => c.Products)
    .Map(cs =>
    {
        cs.MapLeftKey("ProductId");
        cs.MapRightKey("TagId");
        cs.ToTable("ProductTags");
    });
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany<Tag>(s => s.Tags).WithMany(c => c.Products)
    .Map(cs =>
    {
        cs.MapLeftKey("ProductId");
        cs.MapRightKey("TagId");
        cs.ToTable("ProductTradeForTags");
    });
```

After running the application, database was created and table **ProductTradeForTags** is present but table **ProductTags** was missing.

What is the problem and how do I fix it so both tables are created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't share the navigation properties. You will need to add a second set of navigation collections to each:

```
public class Product
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> TradeForTags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> TradeForProducts{ get; set; }
}
```

Then

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany(s => s.Tags).WithMany(c => c.Products)
    .Map(cs =>
    {
        cs.MapLeftKey("ProductId");
        cs.MapRightKey("TagId");
        cs.ToTable("ProductTags");
    });
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasMany(s => s.TradeForTags).WithMany(c => c.TradeForProducts)
    .Map(cs =>
    {
        cs.MapLeftKey("ProductId");
        cs.MapRightKey("TagId");
        cs.ToTable("ProductTradeForTags");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model require to navigate from a Tag to Products and from a Product to Tags.
In this case one association table is enough.
EF should raise an exception but it simply ignores the first configuration.